# matTooltip doesn't take original return value from function calling

Tags: angular, angular-material

= 39" >   {{ getFieldName(element).slice(0, 36) }}...

<label class="icon-label"     *ngIf="getFieldName(element).length < 39">{{  getFieldName(element) }}

in this code, matTooltip doesn't take original return value. It takes only slice value. Why?

I want slice value inside label and original value in matTooltip while hover the label

Comment: Please read through the [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem. You can use stackblitz to create playground with angular.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.